# Apache Beam - Local Class Incompatible Error running a service using a local Spark Master Runner

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, apache-beam, java-11

I am trying to run a pipeline with Apache Beam using the Spark runner by passing a spark master URL

The service that I want to execute is running as a docker container.
The script that contains the Apache Beam pipeline code is in a python file called run_beam_pipeline.py which calls the Run function as below.

```
def run(input_path, output_path, pipeline_args):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    input_patterns = [input_path + '/*.csv']
    global seq  # Adding sequence as a work around of missing validation job
    seq = 0
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        list_of_files = [f for f in listdir(input_path) if isfile(join(input_path, f))]
        logging.info(f"Number of files found {len(list_of_files)}")

        csv_read = (
            p
            | 'Read CSV files' >> ReadCsvFiles(input_patterns)
        )
        # print(csv_read)

        previous_job_output = (
            csv_read
            | f'Dict to Str :' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
            | f'CALL TO Previous JOB :' >> beam.ParDo(Previous_Job())
        )


        another_previous_job_output = (
            previous_job_output
            | f'Str to Dict :' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
            | f'Add SEQ field:' >> beam.Map(add_seq_field)
            | f'Another Previous Job :' >> beam.ParDo(Another_Previous_Job())
        )
        # convert_output


        Current_Job_output = (
            another_previous_job_output
            | 'Combine to List for Current Job' >> beam.combiners.ToList()
            | 'Convert for current job input:' >> beam.Map(covert_to_currentJob_input).with_output_types(Iterable[Iterable[Iterable[str]]])
            | 'JavaPrefix' >> beam.ExternalTransform(
            'my.beam.transform.javaCurrentJob',
            None,
            "localhost:12345") # The Current Job that does the necessary processing is running as a docker container exposed with port 12345 (Sanity check is successful on the container)
        )

        Current_Job_output | 'ConvertToDict' >> beam.ParDo(IterableToDict()) \
            | 'WriteToJSON' >> WriteToText(output_path)
```

Command Executed:

`python3 run_beam_pipeline.py --runner SparkRunner --spark_master_url=spark://0.0.0.0:7077`

This particular pipeline worked successfully when we tried to use the PortableRunner provided by Apache Beam.
However we need to support the use case where we need to point to an external Spark Master URL

I have installed the following versions:

- Apache Spark 3.2.1
- Apache Beam 2.36.0
- Scala 2.13
- Hadoop 3.3.2
- Java 11.0.11
- Python 3.9.0

The Exception trace is as follows which seems to point to a version mismatch between Spark and Scala:

```
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 78989@USBLRNIKAMATH1
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
22/04/12 19:52:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: nikamath
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: nikamath
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(nikamath); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(nikamath); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/04/12 19:52:19 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.2.34:59371 after 84 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: nikamath
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: nikamath
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(nikamath); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(nikamath); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.2.34:59371 after 2 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/91/3lm1_n393t1_403gg2ld0w0w0000gn/T/spark-12b5cd17-5a01-42e5-aee5-e293ef6841b5/executor-b66acada-8b54-4105-86d8-18042a246074/blockmgr-c7d1beca-086b-4698-be34-e8c46344f8f1
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.2.34:59371
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker spark://Worker@192.168.2.34:56851
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.2.34:56851 after 2 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO WorkerWatcher: Successfully connected to spark://Worker@192.168.2.34:56851
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.executor.
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 0 on host 192.168.2.34
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 59378.
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.2.34:59378
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.2.34, 59378, None)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.2.34, 59378, None)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.2.34, 59378, None)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://192.168.2.34:59371/jars/beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.36.0.jar with timestamp 1649773336641
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.2.34:59371 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/12 19:52:20 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://192.168.2.34:59371/jars/beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.36.0.jar to /private/var/folders/91/3lm1_n393t1_403gg2ld0w0w0000gn/T/spark-12b5cd17-5a01-42e5-aee5-e293ef6841b5/executor-b66acada-8b54-4105-86d8-18042a246074/spark-ffe4deaf-3d44-436a-995f-022b9c344068/fetchFileTemp10162053033814894551.tmp
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO Utils: Copying /private/var/folders/91/3lm1_n393t1_403gg2ld0w0w0000gn/T/spark-12b5cd17-5a01-42e5-aee5-e293ef6841b5/executor-b66acada-8b54-4105-86d8-18042a246074/spark-ffe4deaf-3d44-436a-995f-022b9c344068/-7957849861649773336641_cache to /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/work/app-20220412195217-0001/0/./beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.36.0.jar
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO Executor: Adding file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/work/app-20220412195217-0001/0/./beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.36.0.jar to class loader
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 0
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
22/04/12 19:52:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/04/12 19:52:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/04/12 19:52:21 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1),5,main]
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1(Executor.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1$adapted(Executor.scala:423)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure(Executor.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/04/12 19:52:21 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0),5,main]
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1(Executor.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1$adapted(Executor.scala:423)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure(Executor.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/04/12 19:52:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/91/3lm1_n393t1_403gg2ld0w0w0000gn/T/spark-12b5cd17-5a01-42e5-aee5-e293ef6841b5/executor-b66acada-8b54-4105-86d8-18042a246074/spark-ffe4deaf-3d44-436a-995f-022b9c344068
```

What I have tried:

1. Running all Spark Master Node and workers using root priviliges
2. Using different versions of Scala (2.10, 2.11, 2.12, 2.13) and restarting Spark workers and Master each time before running the beam pipeline
3. Hadoop 3.3.2 (Although I do not think it is relevant beacuse we dont use it but gave it a shot anyway)

On doing some reading I believe the issue is mostly beacuse of a version mismatch between one or more of Beam / Spark / Scala and/or Hadoop. Is there a specific version set for Spark / Scala / Hadoop which will resolve this issue?